# Why journalctl does not display log message if I use filtering by unit?

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald, journalctl

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I am seeing some strange behavior when analyzing journalctl logs.

Here's unfiltered output (I used json output to hopefully include all relevant fields):

```
$ journalctl -o json-pretty --since "2018-01-11 12:00:00" --until "2018-01-11 12:00:05"
{
"__CURSOR" : "s=bac060082d1c447a972958f176cdcec7;i=1d2a2e;b=a948062f9f0b4091ae299c0523a99111;m=337bc483bf3;t=5627c5f8a3bae;x=7fd2518d6b70b9d",
"__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP" : "1515661201914798",
"__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP" : "3537916935155",
"_BOOT_ID" : "a948062f9f0b4091ae299c0523a99111",
"_TRANSPORT" : "stdout",
"PRIORITY" : "6",
"SYSLOG_FACILITY" : "3",
"SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER" : "start.sh",
"_PID" : "6474",
"_UID" : "1000",
"_GID" : "1000",
"_COMM" : "start.sh",
"_EXE" : "/bin/bash",
"_CMDLINE" : "/bin/bash /usr/local/malibu/start.sh",
"_CAP_EFFECTIVE" : "0",
"_SYSTEMD_CGROUP" : "/system.slice/malibu.service",
"_SYSTEMD_UNIT" : "malibu.service",
"_SYSTEMD_SLICE" : "system.slice",
"_MACHINE_ID" : "f03ff2ad269ea529c82323dd57f29b00",
"_HOSTNAME" : "terminal",
"MESSAGE" : "2018-01-11 12:00:01.914 DEBUG: malibu.devices.validator.ValidatorPortService$ - health check succeeded"
}
```

As you can see, the output contains a single log message.

But if I add filter by unit name (`-u malibu.service`), this message disappears:

```
$ journalctl -u malibu.service -o json-pretty --since "2018-01-11 12:00:00" --until "2018-01-11 12:00:05"
```

The unit name is exactly equal to `_SYSTEMD_UNIT` field in unfiltered output. Why journalctl does not display it in the filtered version?

**EDIT:** Turns out I was using old version of systemd - 229, while latest is 236, and using newer journalctl fixes this problem. Unfortunately, 229 is the latest available systemd version for 16.04 LTS, so I do not see a sensible workaround for the issue (apart from building latest systemd in user-space and using freshly built journalctl binary directly).

Comment: feel free to move the last paragraph to an answer and accept it (the system will make you wait a couple of days to accept it, in case someone had a better answer).  it's how the system is intended to be used, and you can get extra internet points by people voting on the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was using old version of systemd - 229, while latest is 236, and using newer journalctl fixes this problem. Unfortunately, 229 is the latest available systemd version for 16.04 LTS, so I do not see a sensible workaround for the issue (apart from building latest systemd in user-space and using freshly built journalctl binary directly).